# Return list of all neighboring towns PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

In a program with the following rule:
neighbour(X,Y):- link(X,Y) ; link (Y,X).

There are already a few facts stated of the form link(a,b), etc.

How do I write a procedure all_neighbours(L,X) which returns a list L of all neighbouring towns to X?

My attempt:

```
all_neighbours([Y|Tail],X):- neighbour(X,Y), fail.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't succeed because you always fail at the first fact and never reach remaining facts in the database.

The easiest way is using built-in `findall/3` predicate:

```
all_neighbours(L, X) :- findall(Y, neighbour(X, Y), L).
```

Comment: I can't fix the typo, but the rule should actually be all_neighbours(L, X) **:-** findall(Y, neighbour(X, Y), L).